# Why do I get a stack overflow when I include the pivot in recursive calls in the quicksort algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm in c++ as a project in a lecture. The program works fine when I exclude the pivot from the recursive calls, but sometimes causes a stack overflow error when i include the pivot in either of the recursive calls.

The program malfunctions only for a specific array size, but I can't figure out what relation they have with the errors. For example, the program malfunctions when I give 40, but works just fine for 50.

```
void quicksort(double* arr, int init, int fin) {
    if (init == fin) return;
    if (init == fin - 1) {
        if (arr[init] > arr[fin]) {
            double temp = arr[fin];
            arr[fin] = arr[init];
            arr[init] = temp;
        }
        return;
    }
    int smaller = init - 1;
    double pivot = arr[fin];
    for (int ind = init; ind < fin; ind++) {
        if (arr[ind] < pivot) {
            smaller++;
            double temp = arr[ind];
            arr[ind] = arr[smaller];
            arr[smaller] = temp;
        }
    }
    arr[fin] = arr[smaller + 1];
    arr[smaller + 1] = pivot;
    if(smaller>=init) quicksort(arr, init, smaller);
    if(smaller+2<=fin) quicksort(arr, smaller + 2, fin);
    return;
}
```

This is the code in question. It works fine when i put it this way, but causes errors when i replace

```
if(smaller+2<=fin) quicksort(arr, smaller + 2, fin);
```

with

```
if(smaller+1<=fin) quicksort(arr, smaller + 1, fin);
```

Comment: Welcome to tack Overflow. Could you give us the smallest example you can find of an array that causes the fault?

Comment: Use a debugger when you get the stack overflow. It's a good skill to mandatorily master.

Comment: Use small, systematic test cases like `{1,2}` so you can easily walk through your program by hand.

Comment: I tried using the debugger to go through the basic cases and found out that cases like ```[0,0,0]``` and ```[0,1,0]``` lead to infinite recursion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: "Mandatorily" is overstatement. I've been a professional developer for over a decade, and I never use debuggers. (Not out of principle or anything -- it's 100% fine to use them -- I just like other debugging techniques better.) But I agree with you that the OP needs to learn to debug his code one way or another, and should try a debugger to see if he finds it helpful.

Comment: @ruakh Someone who doesn't know how to use a debugger is not someone I can consider for any development job. In C or C++, it's mandatory.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: I see -- by "mandatory" you mean "mandatory for employment by Matthieu Brucher". Fortunately, I've been successful in my career without ever needing to be employed by you, so I guess that's fine. :-P (Though I only did professional C++ development for a few years in there -- most of my career has been Java -- so perhaps if I'd done more C++ development, I would have come around to liking debuggers more than I do.)

Comment: Note this is an issue specific to [Lomuto partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme). [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) normally includes the pivot and/or elements == pivot in either partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(smaller+1<=fin)` is equivalent to `if(true)` (since  `smaller+1` starts out as `init` and is incremented at most `fin-init` times), so any call with at least three elements will necessarily recurse at that line — and the recursive call may not accomplish anything, if (for example) all three elements are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it.  Suppose the selected pivot element is the smallest value in the partition.  It will move to the beginning of the range.

```
[ 3 5 2 1 4]  // supposed we select 3 as the pivot
[ 2 1 3 5 4]  // after partitioning
[ 3 5 4] // the recursive call for the right "half"
```

If we select 3 as the pivot again, nothing changes in this range.  And thus, when we recurse on the right "half" again, we're in exactly the same situation.  We've not made any progress, so recursion will continue until the stack overflows.

Omitting the pivot from the ranges for the recursive calls guarantees we make progress and thus that the recursion will eventually terminate.